# vscode auto folding on open file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

**What:** Is there any way to open files in vscode and have it auto fold code for you?

**Why:** I only need to see most code a few times before I've memorized it, and at that point a reference with a peeked definition is all I need. Interfaces, classes, and types just take up my realestate. I want more of the most valuable code on the screen at a time. This means I need to hide some or all of the code when files are large.

**Ideally:** I'd like to just close specific types of code (ex. interfaces) for specific types of files (ex. typescript files) for files larger than arbitrary 55 lines long, but I would settle for just auto folding all code.

Comment: That does exist, but only for the import section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503900/6309

Comment: This app seems to be exclusively for this purpose: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=prantlf.fold-on-open]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know that is not possible in vanilla vscode.

There is however an extension you might be interested in, which might do the trick for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bobmagicii.autofoldyeah

If you haven't tried it yet you might also want to check out "Go to symbol in file..."  - it might help you navigate in larger files.

The hotkey for that is command-shift-o (on mac), if you type a colon afterwards it even sorts it into variables/functions etc.

Anyways - short answer, not possible without an extension.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate! I upvoted your answer, but I just found this extension earlier and I'm aware of jump to def/symbol type of thing, but I'm looking for another better option. The problem with autofolding all code in all files is now I have to ctl+k+j on every other  small file to read them. =/ I will continue looking for a clean solution for automatically abstracting away the "unnecessary" information. If nothing comes up, then I'll close this with your answer! Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure if the extension in the answer was updated later but today, using the "magic comment" option, you can fold only the files you want (the big ones for example) to the level you define in comment or all files by type (also to the defined level per type) and you don't need to set the default autofold for all files.